# PHP include is not working?

Tags: php, html

I remember trying this plenty of times and it working but for some reason it isn't working for me now. I am using a local wamp server just to test this. It is not a public site. It isnt including the simple h1 tag that's located in the "/includes/header.php" for some reason.

My index.php code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Weekend Warrior Squad - Homepage</title>
    <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <?php include("/includes/header.php"); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

My header.php code:

```
<header>

<h1>WWS - Weekend Warrior Squad</h1>
    <p>

        We are community based paintball team make the game of paintball 
        more enjoyable for ourselves and others.

    </p>

</header>
```

All recommendations / answers are very much appreciated.

Comment: `/includes/header.php` - if you're going to want and use `/` then use the full server path `/var/user/you/public_html/includes/header.php` or use a relative path such as `includes/header.php` or `../includes/header.php` depending on the location.

Comment: I used the directory, C:/wamp/www/wws/includes/header.php to try to include the header.php into my index.php and still no luck.

Comment: How are you trying to access your initial file? Are you not doing `http://localhost/www/file.php` via browser? I have Wamp also and it worked perfectly fine. Make sure you restart all services if you made any changes to any config files also. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am using the file directory file:///C:/wamp/www/wws/index.php to get to the webpage

Comment: That's not how you access it. Use `http://localhost/www/wws/index.php`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Using that I am getting http://prntscr.com/516aqw

Comment: By accessing it through `file:///...`, you're entirely circumventing your WAMP server. Your primary problem is that **PHP is not getting executed at all** when you do that. Try just `http://localhost/` and figure out what your necessary URL is from there; likely http://localhost/wws/. See the linked duplicate for more solutions to your secondary problem of absolute/relative paths.

Comment: You're doing something wrong then. I don't know what else to tell you that will be of further help, except check your initial installation folder. I installed Wamp last week and had no issues. Restart your computer if you didn't do that after the install, or just re-install. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used wamp but I'm guessing the urls look something like `localhost/project_name/index.php` when you reference the include file as `/includes/` it's actually looking for the file in `localhost/includes/` and the file is not there.

Depending on where your file location is you can step out from it's folder and locate the includes folder.

```
include('../includes/');
```

This will go one folder up from where the file that is calling it. You can use `..` as many times as you like to go to a new level, eg `../../includes`

Comment: Unfortunately that is not working.

Comment: What is your folder structure? you'll need to navigate around using the `../` until you get to the location of where the includes for is.

Comment: the location of the includes folder is, C:\wamp\www\wws\includes

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    include "include/header.php";
?>
```

I think the reason for this is that you do not need the brackets. Try it and see if it works.

Comment: Using this line of code

    <?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>

Did not work :(

Comment: Check your file and directories name and see if there is any spelling error. If it is all okay, check to see if your index page's extension is .php instead of .html. If it is all fine still, try a simple code like echo "" or running a simple for loop echoing from 1-10. If this doesn't works, it means that that is something wrong with your configuration for PHP.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 The require piece of code is also not working. I made sure that the directory and spelling was correct.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Using the error reporting in the code gave me a page of my code basically. http://prntscr.com/5169bq

Comment: @CodiBezouka-Smith That code needs to be wrapped in `<?php` tags. I.e.: `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, are you certain the relative path you set in your `include` is correct?  Temporarily set it to an absolute path to be certain.

<strike>Secondly, you are missing the closing tag for your `h1` in header.php, not sure whether this would affect your current issue but it *could* cause others.</strike>

Edit: I fail.

Comment: The path to the includes folder is correct yes, and the closing h1 tag is on the same line as the starting h1 tag :?

Comment: @CodiBezouka-Smith Whoops completely missed that!  My apologies.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/header.php");

Or else you could use require instead of include.

Comment: Could you give me line of code that is properly used if I am connected through local host wamp server please!?

Comment: Assuming the location of your file is : c:\wamp\www\xyz\includes\header.php